# Weights in $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$ be the set of diagonal matrices. Then for $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a_3 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathfrak{h}$ and $1 \leq i \leq 3$, define $L_i A = a_i$. One can see that the $L_i - L_j$ for $i \neq j$ are the weights with eigenvectors $E_{ij}$ ($1$ in position $(i,j)$, $0$ everywhere else). Then, in Fulton and Harris page 163, they give us this picture

[image]

I don't know what is going on here. In the weight space decomposition of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$ we get the spaces $\mathfrak{g}_{ij}$ are the eigenvectors of $L_i - L_j$ and are spanned by $E_{ij}$.... but what does the picture below *even mean*?

I know this should be obvious but I'm quite confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is an angle preserving depiction of a certain Euclidian space together with some of its elements:

The Euclidean space in question is the real part of the dual ${\mathfrak h}^{\ast}$ of the Cartan subalgebra ${\mathfrak h}$ of ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_3({\mathbb C})$ of diagonal matrices, equipped with the *restriction of the dual of the Cartan-Killing-Form* of ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_3({\mathbb C})$. The depicted elements are combinations of the projections $L_i: {\mathfrak h}\to{\mathbb C}$.

---

*General Theory:* If ${\mathfrak g}$ is a semisimple complex Lie algebra, then its Cartan-Killing form $\kappa_{\mathfrak g}$ is non-degenerate, and its restriction $\kappa_{\mathfrak g}|_{{\mathfrak h}\times{\mathfrak h}}$ is non-degenerate on ${\mathfrak h}$. In particular, it induces an isomorphism ${\mathfrak h}\cong{\mathfrak h}^{\ast}$ along which it can itself be pulled back to a non-degenerate form on ${\mathfrak h}^{\ast}$. It can be proved that the restriction of this form to the ${\mathbb R}$-span ${\mathfrak h}_{\mathbb R}^{\ast}$ of the roots of $({\mathfrak g},{\mathfrak h})$ is even positive definite, hence providing ${\mathfrak h}_{\mathbb R}^{\ast}$ with the canonical structure of a Euclidean vector space.

---

In the example, the Killing form on ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_3({\mathbb C})$ is (up to scalar) given by $(A,B)\mapsto \text{tr}(AB)$, and hence its restriction to ${\mathfrak h}\subset{\mathbb C}^3$ is (up to scalar) the standard bilinear form with $e_1,e_2,e_3$ as an orthonormal basis. In particular, the $L_i-L_j$ are (up to scalar) the duals of $e_i - e_j$, so we e.g. get the cosine $$\left\langle \frac{L_1-L_2}{\|L_1-L_2\|},\frac{L_2-L_3}{\|L_2-L_3\|}\right\rangle = -\frac{1}{2}$$ of the angle between $L_1-L_2$ and $L_2-L_3$ - the angle is therefore 120° as depicted.

Note also that $L_1 + L_2 + L_3 = 0$, so that e.g. $L_1 = \frac{1}{3}\left((L_1 - L_2) + (L_1 - L_3)\right)$, fitting with the picture.

Comment: Isn't the killing form $(A,B) \mapsto tr(ad(A) ad(B))$?

Comment: Right! But up to a scalar it turns out to agree with the usual trace form.

Comment: @nigelvr: Do you have any more questions?

Comment: What I don't get is how does Fulton and Harris draw this diagram before looking at the Killing form and all. Do you know the answer to this? Sorry for commenting on this old post.